# Adding a .bat file to a wix setup project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wix, batch-file

I'm using a wix setup project to install my asp.net application. I put a simple .bat file in the setup project that helps me to install on destination machines.

The .bat file is very simple with just a call to msiexec and then a pause.

Whenever I build my setup project, the .bat file seems to get corrupted. For example, if I try to run the bat file, it says the following:

`D:\Temp\MySetupProject\bin\Debug>n++msiexec /i MySetupProject.msi /l*vx Install.txt
   'n++msiexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.`

D:\Temp\MySetupProject\bin\Debug>pause
   Press any key to continue . . .

Does anyone know why the "n++" is showing up before the msiexec command?

Comment: Is the bat file part of the msi? Or just part of your project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. The encoding on the file was UTF-8 plus signature rather than just UTF-8. Changing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is *only* a guess, but "msiexec" might be being treated as a reserved word (since, preseumably, you are having msi call mis). If so, you might have find if escape characters are required to indicate this, or if some other method is required for the code to make such redundant calls.